# How to hide response from the user?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, response

I'm using s3 to get static content (json) and display it on my web site.

I would like to hide this content from anybody who knows how to use developer tools.

For example: If I open devtools -> network I will be able to see this json.

Is there any way to hide it, such as encrypting it? What would be the best solution with s3?

Comment: Why do you want to hide it? If it is sensitive information, than it shouldn't be sent to the browser in the first place.

Comment: If you encrypt it, your JavaScript has to be able to decrypt it. The user can just set a breakpoint after it's decrypted and view that.

Comment: it's not sensitive, but i worked on this content too long, so i dont want the user to just copy this json in one click:) of course he can write scrapper to extract this content, but this is already another problem.

Comment: @Barmar if it's minified js app, how the user will be able to set a breakpoint?

Comment: There are JS beutifiers that expand minified code.

Comment: @Bramar oh i didnt know that)

Comment: You could try using a packer such as http://dean.edwards.name/packer/ This will make it hard to read and get back, but it will always still be retrievable in a browser.

Comment: All you can do is make it harder, you can't make it impossible. As the other comment said, don't send something to the client if you really don't want the user to see it.

Comment: Barmar, Get Off My Lawn
Got it, thanks)